# How can I edit the automatic reply in outlook using c#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am developing a little outlook Add-In, wich gives the option on the appointement-contextmenu to automatically fill out and set the start/ end the of the out of office message. I have managed to extend the contextmenu and get the start-/ endtime of the chosen appointement.

Now I would like to know, how that I can access the out of office template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

You may find the [Automating Out of Office in Outlook (VBScript)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Automating-Out-of-Office-bc0edb1e) sample code helpful. Consider using EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.