# Outlook Add-In: how to automatically reply based on custom logic?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

### Question

Is it possible with an Outlook add-in to automatically reply only to certain emails/senders, based on custom logic? If so, how?

### Examples

Such an add-in might send an automatic reply only to senders not in contacts, or only to senders whose email has been verified by an external service (which the add-in calls to check). This automatic reply might be:

> Thanks for your email! I prioritize emails from verified senders. You can verify yourself for free [here](https://example.com).

The sender who receives that message could then click the link and verify through the external service. Then, for future emails, the automatic reply would NOT apply to that sender.

### Background

Outlook has an automatic reply option in settings, but its functionality is limited to setting a specific message for internal senders and a different one for external senders, plus choosing whether to only use the automatic reply with contacts. There's no built in ability to accomplish what's described in the examples above.

### Other Questions and Answers (Possibly Relevant)

- [Office-js: How I can reply automatically with Outlook Web Add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482098/office-js-how-i-can-reply-automatically-with-outlook-web-add-in): This may be relevant, but it's hard to tell because the link in the answer is broken now (the answer is from almost 4.5 years ago).
- [How can I edit the automatic reply in outlook using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144912/how-can-i-edit-the-automatic-reply-in-outlook-using-c-sharp): Also might be relevant, but also has a broken link in the answer (which is from almost 7 years ago).

---

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook web add-ins are designed for running for the currently selected item. So, the user should select a particular item in Outlook to activate the add-in. Unlike VSTO where you could handle incoming emails by handling the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`.

As soon as you have got an instance of the incoming email you can use the [MailItem.Reply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reply(method)) method which creates a reply, pre-addressed to the original sender, from the original message.

Finally, you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
- [How To: Change an Outlook e-mail message before sending using C# or VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/12/outlook-change-message-before-sending/)

Comment: Are VSTO add-ins still supported, or are only web add-ins supported now? Looks like VSTO is quite an old framework.

Comment: I know add-ins can filter incoming mail without the user selecting that mail first. Is there any way to do something similar with replying to mail?

Comment: VSTO is based on the COM technology (Office COM add-ins) and lives now without any deadline. Web add-ins are still very limited in their functionality. But the purpose of both technologies are different. VSTO add-ins can be run on Windows and desktop editions of Office applications while web based add-ins are universal, but limited in their functionality. Graph API that can be used in web add-ins adds some functionality to them.

Comment: I see, so VSTO does not work on web versions of Outlook? That's unfortunately too much of a constraint for my use case, I believe.

Comment: VSTO add-ins are for desktop editions of Outlook only (or other Office applications like Word, Excel, PowerPoint).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Eugene Astafiev. I know add-ins can categorize incoming mail, e.g. move/copy them to different folders. Would it be possible to detect incoming mail in that sense and then have the add-in call out to an external service to send an auto reply in that way? For example:
1. Add-in copies incoming email to Unverified Sender folder.
2. Add-in hits external API endpoint.
3. External sends auto reply email, using SMTP or otherwise.

Comment: I'd suggest posting new questions in a separate thread.

Comment: good point. Just posted that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008693/outlook-add-in-how-to-simulate-automatic-reply-with-external-service

Comment: wanted to check my understanding of what you said above: Do VSTO add-ins work only on Windows or also on other computers? Do they work on mobile (iOS/Android)?

Comment: VSTO add-ins can be run on Windows only. Moreover, they can be run by the desktop Office applications only.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook web add-ins currently require the context of an item to run. [Event based add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) will run in the context of an item without users having to explicitly launch an add-in to complete their tasks. However, an OnMessageSelected event, you requested is not a part of the web add-ins product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: One clarification: the automatic replies I'm imagining here would be sent on receiving new messages (just like the default automatic reply feature), not on an `OnMessageSelected` event. The only difference is that the automatic reply would only be sent if some other condition were met. (Some version of this is possible with Gmail, since the Boomerang for Gmail add-on lets the user set specific emails the automatic reply shouldn't be sent to.) Does this clarification change anything about what you said?

Comment: No, as I described in the post here, web add-ins don't provide anything for handling incoming emails without selecting them in Outlook. So, web add-ins work under the context of currently selected item whether it is a event-based activation or not.

Comment: I submitted a feature request here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-outlook-web-add-ins-to-run-without-item-context/idi-p/3136821