# Outlook Add-In: how to simulate automatic reply with external service?

Tags: email, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

### Background

I previously asked this question: [Outlook Add-In: how to automatically reply based on custom logic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977856/outlook-add-in-how-to-automatically-reply-based-on-custom-logic/70978643?noredirect=1#comment125515724_70978643)

As the answerers @EugeneAstafiev and @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT noted, Outlook web add-ins can only run on a currently selected item. This does not work for an automatic reply use case, since automatic replies should send on receiving a new email, regardless of whether the user has selected it.

### Question

Despite this, I know add-ins *can* categorize incoming mail, e.g. move/copy them to different folders. Would it be possible to detect incoming mail in that sense and then have the add-in call out to an external service to send an automatic reply in that way?

### Example

For example:

1. Add-in copies incoming email to folder.
2. Add-in hits external API endpoint.
3. External service sends auto reply email (perhaps using SMTP or similar?).

### Clarifications

I'm *not* looking to use the built-in automatic replies feature in Outlook, since that has very limited options. (Roughly speaking, it can only send one message to all senders or one to contacts and another to non-contacts.) I want this simulated automatic reply to be sent based on custom logic, e.g. whether the external service has verified the sender's email.

---

Is this possible? If so, any recommendations on how best to implement it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with COM based add-ins (VSTO based ones).

The [Application.NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID specified in the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

If you need to handle any specific folder in Outlook and process only items dropped to the folder you may use the [Items.ItemAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) event which is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. Note, this event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than sixteen).

You may consider your VSTO add-in as a regular windows .net application. So, standard mechanisms can be used to make a web call. For example, you may find the [Calling Web Services with HttpWebRequest, WebClient and HttpClient](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/06/01/calling-web-services.aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with an Outlook web add-in? My understanding is that VSTO add-ins are very old and don't work with Outlook on the web. For what I'm trying to build I don't think they're universal enough.

Comment: Nope. Web add-ins work under the currently selected item in Outlook. That means you need to select an item in Outlook to be able to activate a web add-in. But you are right - VSTO add-ins work in Outlook desktop for Windows only. At the same time you get a rich API.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the feature to invoke outlook add-ins without any item context is not a part of the product.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: I submitted a feature request to this effect here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/allow-outlook-web-add-ins-to-run-without-item-context/idi-p/3136821